Testing if a git branch already contains a commit, modulo metadata
Is there a way to check if a given branch contains a commit, excluding metadata (author, commiter, timestamp)?
Context: I have a repository with lots of old branches that have been rebased before being merged, but the original branch has not been deleted. So if I simply compare the commits themselves, the hashes do not match. Also, because they are old, if I do git cherry-pick of the commits, this causes conflicts due to more recent changes (otherwise, I'd get an empty commit and know it has been merged). But if I could do something like git contains-commit <commit> <branch>, where only the file diffs themselves are considered, I'd get some results that would tell me "this commit has been applied in the past", therefore the old branch can be deleted.
It seems git cherry might help, but I couldn't find a way to use it in the "negative".

As much as this can be satisfied git cherry is probably close to what you want. Not sure what you mean by "couldn't find a way to use it in the negative" - cherry tells you commits that it sees as part of the branch prefixed by - as already merged and + not merged. But if commits have had some adjustments to resolve conflicts done as part of their rebase, they will probably still show up as unmerged.

If you want to make sure a commit is part of a branch, try git merge-base commit the-branch (any order). If the result is the commit Id you provided, it has been merged

If git cherry-pick would result in merge conflicts, I don't think git cherry can help.

You can use git cherry to find the commits that have not been taken.
Consider this history:
--o--A--B--R'--S'--T'--C--D   <-- main
   \
     R--S--T"--U              <-- feature
         \
           T                  <-- (abandoned, was feature)

Here, the branch feature was rebased onto main some time ago, when it had only R, S, T (giving us commits R', S', T'). Later, commit T was rewritten (to T") and another commit U was made on top.
Now use
git cherry main feature

and it will list
+ U
+ T"
- S
- R

which tells us that R and S are already in main, but T" and U are not. Since T" is a modification of T it is not recognized as being available in main.
Also, if one of the commits had conflicts when they were rebased, they would also have been altered such that they are not recognized anymore.
